# Asterisk (*) in windows batch file command line argument gets expanded

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a batch script that takes arguments from the command line. One of the arguments has a * in it. In spite of putting the argument in quotes, the * gets expanded before the argument gets used in the batch script.

I am using the following code to parse the arguments:

```
set CMDLINE_ARGS=%~1
shift 
:get_args 
if "%~1" == "" goto execute
set CMDLINE_ARGS=%CMDLINE_ARGS% %~1
shift
goto :get_args
```

This works on Windows Server 2003 but not on Server 2008 for some reason.

Comment: What would you expect this to do and what does it do now? To what is it expanded?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I did anything like this but take a look at

```
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

Not sure what Windows Server 2008 defaults to.

Comment: Won't change anything if it works on one system and not on the other one. Besides, that's not a `for` loop.